# WPF , How to execute an async method many times simultaneously and in same time?

Tags: wpf, async-await, parallel-processing, real-time, parallel.for

I am writing a **WPF project** to **simulate video** display in different structures like buildings.

In this project, I use a special type of binary video with bin extension, in which the colors are stored as red, green and blue.

I have 2 methods, the first one is **"ReadDisplayBinFrames"**, which has 2 tasks of reading bin video and displaying it on the structure. Of course, since these two tasks are **asynchronous**, I defined the method as **async**.

```
public async Task ReadDisplayBinFrames(Product product, bool PlayMode)
    {
        BinFile.SetPlayMode(PlayMode);

        int currentFrameNumber = 0;
        for (int i = 0; BinFile.IsPlayMode == true; i++)
        {
            for (currentFrameNumber = (int)product.LastFrameRead; currentFrameNumber <= product.BinFiles.TotalGame; currentFrameNumber++)
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    product.BinFiles.GetSphereColorFromBin(product.BinFiles.Read(currentFrameNumber), product.Wiring);
                    product.LastFrameRead = currentFrameNumber;
                    Debug.WriteLine($"LastFrameRead {product.LastFrameRead}");


                    product.Wiring.SetSphereColor(product.DelayPlay);
                });

                if (currentFrameNumber >= product.BinFiles.TotalGame)
                {
                    product.LastFrameRead = 0;
                }

                if (animPlayingMode == AnimPlayingMode.SerialAsync)
                {
                    BinFile.SetPlayMode(false);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Since I have a list of structures and I need to be able to display a video on each of them at the **same time**, I defined a method called **"PlayBin"**.

```
private async void PlayBin()
    {
        InitBinList();

        for (int i = 0; i < Products.Count; i++)
        {
            if (animPlayingMode == AnimPlayingMode.ParallelSynchronous)
            {
                Parallel.Invoke(async () =>
                {
                    await ReadDisplayBinFrames(Products[i], true);
                    Debug.WriteLine($"LedProducts Count: {Products[i].LastFrameRead} of Product {i}");
                });
            }
            else
            {
                await ReadDisplayBinFrames(Products[i], true);
                Debug.WriteLine($"LedProducts Count: {Products[i].LastFrameRead} of Product {i}");
            }

        }
    }
```

When I display the video on one structure, it is displayed without any problem, but when I increase the number of structures (for example, 6), the playback speed decreases slightly compared to the case when there was only one structure, and after a while, the coordination is lost. and each goes forward or backward a few frames.

[Videos Of Software Performance](https://www.mediafire.com/file/kfus18kzax6502u/Captured+From+Software.zip/file)

Comment: Are you sure your code isn't doing something funny with currentFrameNumber ? Theirs a dependency between that and product.LastFrameRead in your for loop and the code that's executing inside and outside Task.run - have you tried getting rid of Task.Run btw ?

Comment: Have you seen the attached videos?
Yes, I tried a lot to get rid of the async method and to do it simultaneously, but every time, nothing was displayed, or the software hung completely, or in the best case, several frames at the same time. It was displayed!
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: In that case there's  bug(s) somewhere in your code if you're seeing these issues you mentioned - i think running things async is only clouding things.

Comment: A good way to help with this is to create unit tests that executes ReadDisplayBinFrames with  different parameters - have you tried that ?

Comment: You are right, I should write a test, but I am not very professional in test writing! I was thinking of changing the ReadDisplayBinFrames method to a parallel.for method

Comment: Just making things parallel isn't going to magically fix any underlying bugs in your implementation - in fact it only makes things worse by introducing hard to reproduce errors.  Get rid of this parallel / async stuff and look at refactoring your code - particularly the inner for loop use of currentFrameNumber. Try replacing it with a while loop with explicit exit condiitions. Also  pay attention to how you're updating currentFrameNumber and product.LastFrameRead - i suspect the way you're updating these two variables asynchronously is causing issues.

Comment: In the ReadDisplayBinFrames method, I defined the For loop variable locally without using the value in the input class of the function, but it still didn't make much of a difference, and after a short time, the frames became irregular again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parallel.Invoke` does not support async methods. It expects to execute simple void delegates (e.g. `Action<T>`). This means, the executed delegates will always run synchronously.

Your code is a good piece of example why passing an async lambda as argument for an `Action` introduces a potential bug: because the caller of the delegate expects an `Action`, it won't `await` the `async` method. The `async` method will return the `Task`, and the caller will continue immediately (instead of awaiting this `Task`).

In your case, `Parallel.Invoke` will continue *before* the `async` methods have run to completion. This will lead to dropping the `async` context and to unexpected behavior.

Also note, that an `async` method must always return a `Task` or `Task<T>` (except the method is an event handler).

Instead of `Parallel.Invoke`, you should always use `Task.WhenAll` to execute a number of asynchronous methods and wait for them all to finish:

```cs
// Always let an async method return 'Task' or 'Task<T>' 
// and await it properly!
private async Task PlayBinAsync()
{
  InitBinList();

  if (animPlayingMode == AnimPlayingMode.ParallelSynchronous)
  {
    var runningTasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Products.Count; i++)
    {
      Task runningTask = ReadDisplayBinFrames(Products[i], true);
      runningTasks.Add(runningTask);

      Debug.WriteLine($"LedProducts Count: {Products[i].LastFrameRead} of Product {i}");
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(runningTasks);
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < Products.Count; i++)
  {
    await ReadDisplayBinFrames(Products[i], true);
      runningTasks.Add(runningTask);

      Debug.WriteLine($"LedProducts Count: {Products[i].LastFrameRead} of Product {i}");
  }
}
```